# SItecore XP 10 on Docker: how to install a package when the bin/ folder is read-only?

Tags: packages, docker, container

I am testing Sitecore 10 using docker containers.
I followed the guide in [Sitecore docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html)
Everything seems to work fine, but I had some problems while installing new packages.
For example I wanted to install the Sitecore.ManagementServices module, but the installation stopped with the error "Background process failed: Failed to delete the file 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\GraphQL.dll'.
It looks like the c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder is read-only when installing packages.

As a workaround, I unpacked the files from the package and put them on my deploy/platform folder, in order to let the WatchDirectory script to copy them to c:\inetpub\wwwroot, and it works.
But this is not a long-term solution.
Do I have to change something in the docker-compose.override.yml file in order to be able to install packages ?

Comment: It's not really how to Docker. You're meant to have a known basis container state that you then deploy everything you need to. You and everyone else on your team can then easily get up and going by just dockering up and running the solution publish.

Comment: If you want packages to be part of your base docker image, you should build a layer of your own to put "on top" basically, and share that in your in house registry.

Answer (score 3):

The sitecore.aspnet.gettingstarted didn't install SXA to the Sitecore XP0 instance, so I needed to modify the docker files in order to add SPE and SXA to my images.

Here is how to do it, if anyone is in the same situation, and need to add a module to their docker-compose file:

in .env add the following variables:

[image: changes in .env]

You'll need mssql to add some databases, solr to add some index and cm to add the modules.
In the docker-compose.override.yml, add information about SPE and SXA in the arguments part of the declaration if those images:

For mssql:
[image]

For solr:
[image]

For cm:
[image]

Those arguments are read by the Dockerfile situated respectively in:

./docker/build/mssql/Dockerfile
./docker/build/solr/Dockerfile
./docker/build/cm/Dockerfile

mssql/Dockerfile:
[image]

solr/Dockerfile:
[image]

cm/Dockerfile:
[image]

You just build your images in Powershell with the command:
docker-compose build